# Custom protocol handler in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have a mobile product, which runs in a WebView, and talks to our iOS / Android SDK's over a custom `scheme://` (inserting an iframe with this in the URL). This is notoriously difficult to debug, and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to catch these calls in a custom Chrome extension. I understand I can "redirect" using `navigator.registerProtocolHandler`, but I'd like to be able to "respond" (in the case of our SDK that means injecting Javascript into the page) to these calls. Is this possible?

Comment: What about [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)?

Comment: @wOxxOm we already use that, but we want to emulate the SDK's responses manually instead of having them automatically run (the WebView has quite aggressive hard timeouts on the SDK side).